# Is it possible to make an async function return a mongoose Query instead of a Promise?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, mongoose, async-await

## Setup

Let's say we have some documents `Foo` and `Bar`. `Foo` has a `name` field that can be used to identify documents other than using the document's `_id`. `Bar` contains a reference to a `Foo` document.

```
const fooSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    unique: true
  }
});
const Foo = <any>mongoose.model<any>('Foo', fooSchema);

const barSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  foo: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Foo'
  },
  date: Date
});
const Bar = <any>mongoose.model<any>('Bar', barSchema);
```

Now suppose we have the `name` of a `Foo` document, but not its `_id`. We want to find all `Bar` documents which reference that `Foo` document. So we write a function that first finds the `Foo` document with the given `name`, then use it to find `Bar` documents.

```
barSchema.statics.findBarWithFooName = async function(name: string) {
  let foo = await Foo.findOne({ name: name });
  return Bar.find({ foo: foo });
};
```

And we can use this function by writing:

```
let bars = await Bar.findBarWithFooName('fooName');
```

## Problem

However, we also want to sort the `bars` by date. Normally, with mongoose's Query builder, we can write something like so:

```
let bars = await Bar.find({})
                    .sort('date');
```

However, if we instead used the function that we wrote:

```
let bars = await Bar.findBarWithFooName('fooName')
                    .sort('date');
```

We would instead get an error:

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise
>   rejection (rejection id: 1): TypeError:
>   Bar.findBarWithFooName(...).sort is not a function

## Debugging

Upon investigating with `console.log(bars)`, I discovered that when we call `Bar.find({})`, the resulting object is mongoose's `Query` object.

However, when we call `Bar.findBarWithFooName('fooName')`, the resulting object is a `Promise { <pending> }`. So it makes sense that the method `sort` doesn't exist on a `Promise { <pending> }`.

## Question

My question is then, why is it that in the first case, it returns a `Query`, but in the second case, it returns a `Promise { <pending> }`? And what can I do to make `findBarWithFooName` return a `Query` so that I can continue to build the query, instead of a `Promise { <pending> }`?

I am aware that one solution I can use is to take `await Foo.findOne({ name: name })` out of `findBarWithFooName`, and simply take a `_id` as parameter instead of a `name`. However, I am trying to abstract away the process of having to find a `Foo` first, which is why I am trying to create a single function that returns a `Query` instead.

Comment: I think the only thing you can do is make a function that returns a `Promise` to use `async/await` with mongo/mongoose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### No

It's impossible to make an `async function` return a custom object instead of a `Promise` - not even a promise subclass.

### No

You cannot make your `findBarWithFooName` return a query anyway, since it has to wait for `Foo.findOne` before the `Bar.find` is even called and constructs the Query object you are looking for.

To solve your problem, you will need to return some wrapper for the query - you cannot `return` the query directly as it is thenable and does get implicitly awaited. The call would then look like

```
let bars = await ( unwrap(await Bar.findBarWithFooName('fooName')).sort('date') );
```

with `unwrap` being something that takes the Query out of the wrapper. As a wrapper you can use anything without a `then` method - it can be a closure, an object with a property, an array with a single element…

Comment: What's unwrap? A jquery method?

Comment: @Normal No, nothing to do with jQuery. It depends on the wrapper you use. You could `const wrap = query => ({query})`, then `unwrap` would be `wrapped => wrapped.query`. Or you could have `const wrap = query => () => query`, then you'd use `const unwrap = wrapped => wrapped();`. Or `const wrap = query => [query]` and `const unwrap = wrapped => wrapped[0];`. Those are just the three example approaches I mentioned in my answer, there's many more.